# How do I reach the different properties on my Promotion, from the Adjustments collection?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We have configured Sitecore Commerce with a number of Promotions. One of them looks like this:

[image]

And the promotion code works fine. If added to the basket, the benefits of the promotion kick in and the basket total reflects this.

But my question is; how can I access the properties of this promotion in the .Adjustments collection on my cart?

Currently I have this bit of code:

```
var firstPromotion = cart.Adjustments.First();
if (firstPromotion != null)
{
    model.PromotionsApplied = true;
    model.AppliedPromoText = firstPromotion.Description;
    model.AppliedPromoResult = firstPromotion.Amount.ToCurrency(cart.Total.CurrencyCode);
    if (!firstPromotion.IsCharge)
    {
        model.AppliedPromoResult = new HtmlString("-" + model.AppliedPromoResult);
    }
}
```

The problem is; .Description does not give me the expected "Description" field from the promotion itself. And as for the other properties, "Text" and "Cart Text" - these are not mapped to the Adjustments object I get back.

[image]

I am assuming I could possibly get these properties via the `GetPropertyValue` method. But if so, what would these be named?   Or can the `Adjustment` be cast as a more specific entity like maybe `PromotionAdjustment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's not a bug, it's an undeveloped feature.

At least that is the answer I got from Sitecore support.  So the core issue is; `.Description` is actually intended to give you the "Cart Text" content. So you don't really need to access other properties (although I would still consider this to be convenient) - this is all taken care of for you.

The problem is; the Pricing and Promotion Manager UI (the SPEAK application) only works on the "en" language. You cannot switch language in any way (short of creating new user accounts and changing their content editing language) - so when you request `.Description` in a site running anything other than "en" you just get the default text back.

And this was, what was throwing me off course on this.

Sitecore Support did provide me with a workaround for this, but it has no public reference number (since it's not a "bug").  Refer to ticket 498830 if you need this issue solved.